# jQuery if/else sum of input fields

Tags: jquery

on my form, i have some inputs, and i want to sum them all.

```
<input class="soma" maxlength="1" type="number" />
<input class="soma" maxlength="1" type="number" />
<input class="soma" maxlength="1" type="number" />
...
```

My jQuery script to sum:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mostrar_resultado').click(function() {
        var valor = 0; 

        $('.soma').each(function(i){ 
            valor = parseInt($(this).val()) + valor ;
        });

        if (valor >= 10){
            $('#resposta').html("Sonolência excessiva diurna, deve ser investigada. Procure um médico!")
        } else if (valor <=9){
            $('#resposta').html("Você não possui sonolência excessiva diurna!")
        }
        if (valor == 0){
            $('#resposta').html("");
            $('.recebe_valor').val("0");
        }

    })

});
```

**what is my problem:**

**I want to show some text if the user don't filled the fields, another if the sum of all is is greater or equal 10 and another if the sum is less than 10 and greater or equal to 1.**

And currently my `IF/ELSE` is not like that!

How to fix this like my description?

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: `what is my problem?` You tell us. We know what is supposed to happen, but not what actually happens. How does the code above fail? Does an error occur?

Comment: lol.. my `ELSE/IF` is not like my description below my `what is my problem?` phrase.

Comment: @Preston you should post exactly how it is - That way we don't have to guess at what your problem might be :)

Comment: Apart from anything else you've got a typo, it's `maxlength`, not `maxlenght`. Spelling is important.

Comment: The problem is that your code does not reflect your requirements. What does prevent you to implement it?

Comment: Tell us what valor is when it gets to the if statements. Also, not sure if this is your problem, but you should specify your radix of parseInt everytime, or it _may_ do strange stuff. so change `parseInt($(this).val())` to `parseInt($(this).val(), 10)`

Comment: You misspelled "maxlength", but I don't think that's part of your problem. It seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/EStN7/

Comment: i Don't know why you want to close this question?.. I don't know how to setup my if/else like my description in **BOLD** on the question.. is that what i want...

Comment: I would also guess that it has something to do with trying to add a `NaN`, which is what happens when you parse a non-integer string as an integer.

Comment: Preston, people are trying to close your question because you tell us what you want, but not what you are getting.  We have to know what your code is actually doing before we can help you get it to do what you want it to do.

Comment: But i put this on my question, on `my Jquery script` ... my IF/ELSE is not like what i whant. SOme guy post here one answer, but he have deleted.. This Answer solve my problem... but he have deleted.

Comment: Preston, in the future, telling us "it is not like what I want' is **not** helpful. Tell us what it **is** giving you, and then we can piece together what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

You should be aware of how parseInt works.

The default radix is 10, but it is a good practice to specify it anyway.

In case of unsuccessful parsing, the result is `NaN`. Adding it to any number will result in `NaN`.

```
>>> parseInt("5")
5
>>> parseInt("")
NaN
>>> parseInt("",10)
NaN
>>> parseInt("a")
NaN
>>> parseInt("a",16)
10
>>> val = parseInt("5")
5
>>> val += parseInt("")
NaN
```

So, you can check to see if your `valor` is `NaN` by using `isNaN()`, or your can set a flag and count only valid input.

I created a sketch [here](http://jsfiddle.net/masteram/c5wAE/).